# How to have a server run and display a terminal instance?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

I have a Ruby Program. I would like a user to type in a URI and have a terminal window display in-browser that is running an instance of the .rb file. The user should be able to type into the browser as they would if they were running the .rb file locally on their terminal machine and have the server respond. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean you want something like an online terminal or an online irb?

Comment: Sorry for being a smartass about this, but if you're asking such a question, I doubt you should be enabling such functionality on your server. Anyways, you need something like Socket.io on the client side with a socket.io compatible ruby server. Google a bit.

Comment: not completely sure i understand the requirements but you could have them use the ssh chrome [plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo) and then configure their profiles on the server to give them the appropriate access to the ruby program.

Comment: Are you talking about reading from STDIN?  The web works quite differently.

Comment: Why do you want to do this. The security implications are sort of ginormous. It's more like remoting than client server over the web.

Comment: Take a look at TryRuby: http://tryruby.org/levels/1/challenges/0 .. and the source: https://github.com/Sophrinix/TryRuby

Comment: **mohamed.magdy:** I'm looking for an online terminal. I have the ruby program already written.

**silicon** thanks I don't want them to have to do any configuration.

**casper** thanks i just cloned it, look @ the source now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this will work.  Linode uses this to allow end users to login to their slices.  Might be able to use the same thing in this instance.

http://wiki.contribs.org/Ajaxterm